# Can I set up ICollectionChanged so that new items are always added to the end even though it has Sort Descriptions

Tags: c#, wpf, list, sorting, listview

I have an ObservableCollection that is wrapped by a ListCollectionView.
The ListCollectionView is displayed in a grid (XamDataGrid).

When I add items to my observable collection those items are exposed by the ListViewCollection sorted in the order defined by the SortDescriptions property.

Here's the problem. I would like new items to appear at the bottom of my grid even though the existing ones are currently sorted. Next time the user sorts (by clicking at the column header) the new items should be sorted.

I'm struggling to find a solution to this problem. Anyone's had a similar issue?

Comment: Is ListViewCollection a class you wrote yourself, or are you trying to say ListCollectionView or CollectionViewSource? Anyway, do a custom sort. No, you can't "set up ICollectionChanged" in any sense to do anything. Did you see any configuration options in the documentation? (*The what?*) What could that even possibly mean? Do you understand which class is responsible for the sorting?

Comment: So you don't want to use SortDescriptions at all, you want to sort yourself.  Go for it.

Comment: Changed to ListCollectionView. Thanks for pointing that out Ed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution A: Manage the sorting yourself behind the scenes

Easiest thing to do here is sort the data behind the scenes (you can use LINQ for that), then assign it to the grid *without* the sort descriptions.  Then as you add items, they'll just appear at the end of the collection. When you click on a header, intercept that and sort yourself accordingly.

### Solution B: Add another `SortDescription`

Another approach is to add another property to your data and create a primary sort on that field first, then by what you actually want to sort on.  For instance, you could add a boolean called `existedBeforeSort`.  If you can't modify your model, you can do it via an extension where you store the actual value in a dictionary keyed on the object itself. (That's sort of how `DependencyProperties` work, but this can be for any object since you're managing the storage.)

Now, in the grid, as you click a sort header, the first thing you do is set the `existedBeforeSort` property on all items to `true`.  Since your first `SortDescription` is based on that field, followed by the sort descriptions generated by clicking on the headers, all newly added items will appear at the bottom as you wanted.

The trick to this second approach is making sure as you click on sort headers, you manually make sure your `SortDescription` based on your `existedBeforeSort` property is always inserted first.  In essence, you're hijacking the implied `SortDescriptions` and injecting yours to supersede theirs.  Shouldn't be too difficult though.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Very good answer!! Thanks!
 I went for the second solution. Only change I made was to make existedBeforeSort an int so that the order of the items added since the last sort would be maintained. I just increment this int as new items are added. All the other items get existedBeforeSort set to 0.

Comment: Glad I could help!  Good catch on that int change too!